# How to fix usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] issue?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

When I try to run setup.py give this error.

```
C:\chatbot\python-telegram-bot\python-telegram-bot>python setup.py
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

C:\chatbot\python-telegram-bot\python-telegram-bot>

How to Fix this issue ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Generally, you need to do something like `python setup.py <some_action>` -- e.g. `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py develop`

Comment: Actually I want to run this app. Already try "python setup.py install" "build" and "develop". But it will not work.